# Navigate to url when window closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a web application for on-line test. For this I have a page `Start_test.php` which has a start button on click of which `new_window` opens without `tool-bar` which is fine. Now, my question is 'When gets completed then this new_window will be closed and `start_test.php` will be redirected to another page `finish.php`?' Can I do this?

Comment: "When finished it will be closed" by you or by user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.
In `new_window` use

```
function redirect(){
   window.opener.location="finish.php";
}
window.onbeforeunload = redirect;
```